# Which Loops is efficient??

Tags: loops

According to my knowledge loops are used in programming to do repetitive task..
There are certain types of loops like for, while, do while etc... and their syntax differs from each other like for example in while loops we intialize the counter outside and check the conditions in while() and ++ || -- inside the code block, whereas in for loop we do all certain things like initialization,condition checking and ++ || -- in for keyword.

So my question is **which loops is efficient and occupies less memory**

Comment: the difference between the loops you mentioned are not in terms of efficiency but in where they should be used :)

Comment: There's no discernible difference in performance between the scenarios you have described.  In each one the same operations are being performed.

Answer (score 1):

The loops you listed aren't really going to differ in memory usage or "efficiency". Rather, each one should be used in different situations. A `for` loop is often used when one needs to iterate through some object that contains multiple indexes or lines etc. For example (Java):

```
for(int i = 0; i<fooString.length(); i++){
    fooCharArray[i] = fooString.charAt(i);
}
```

You could also achieve the same with a `while` loop:

```
int i = 0;
while(i<fooString.length()){
    fooCharArray[i] = fooString.charAt(i);
    i++;
}
```

Often, recursion can achieve the sams results as loops, too (though in my example it'd seem slightly wasteful, since a loop could do it so easily). So really, it's more about **what you're doing, what's easiest for you, and what makes it the most readable/understandable for you and other programmers.**